# how can I convert a kdb dictionary to table

Tags: kdb

I have a dictionary whose key is string and value is float. How can I convert this dictionary to table with column name being the key and each value filled in?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share a sample dictionary?

Comment: Hi Cathal, my keys are Apple, Banana, Pear; and my values are 1, 2, 3. I want to get a table with column Apple, Banana, Pear and value for each column is 1, 2, 3. I tried flip, but it gives me a rank error

Comment: @AlisonPark If someone asks for a sample they mean a sample in kdb syntax, not an example written in English. It makes it much easier for people to understand your problem and help you when they're looking at the same (kdb) object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `enlist` each dictionary entry before attempting `flip` as kdb expects a list of values for each column as opposed to a single value.

```
q)flip enlist each`Apple`Banana`Pear!1 2 3
Apple Banana Pear
-----------------
1     2      3
```

Comment: You can also just `enlist` the whole dictionary instead of enlisting each & flipping i.e. ``enlist`Apple`Banana`Pear!1 2 3`` (because a table is just a list of dictionaries)